# --Headless mode is not working in chrome version 77

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Previously I am working on chrome 76 version then my headless option in selenium testing is running fine when the chrome is updated with version 77, this is not working I use this for writing basic automation tests in selenium even if I mention chrome options to --headless that doesn't work for me. It directly opens the browser but if we use --headless the browser need not to open but in my case, it was opening. Please suggest me a way to get this issue resolved

Comment: Yeah, seems like i have this issue too so +1

Comment: Wondering if you found any solution.

Comment: any news on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, right now the chrome is updated again and for the latest update to 78 version, this --headless mode is working fine. Now if I use 77 chrome driver its working for me.